# Why does ssh-copy-id with a non-`id_rsa` file on Mac OSX tell me that my key already exists?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I am trying to use a non-standard key name to copy to the remote server but it's telling me that the key already has been copied:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i /Users/wwerner/.ssh/my_other_key me@example
/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system.
```

I know that's a lie, though, because when I do this:

```
ssh me@example "cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2"
```

Shows me my `id_rsa.pub` but not `my_other_key.pub`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Red Hat issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1093168#c1) held the key* to my issue:

> I had the same issue - seems to have something to do with a user ssh config - I renamed mine, re-did it, and it worked

Oh ho, thought I - I do have an ssh config, and this isn't the first key I've copied, *and* I'm specifying `example` in the file instead of having to type `subdomain.example.com`.

So I tried specifying the *full* domain:

```
ssh-copy-id -i /Users/wwerner/.ssh/my_other_key me@subdomain.example.com                                                                                                                                                                                        $? 1  12:34:54
/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys

Number of key(s) added:        1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'me@subdomain.example.com'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

And boom, it worked. Excellent.

*<sub>Hah hah</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I met the same issue and found that ssh-copy-id script does not work if you have `LogLevel quiet` in your ssh config: it parses ssh output for `Permission denied` output and does not get it.

Comment: This.  This is the answer!

Comment: @Victor Ashik, on which end of the connection does the ssh config file that causes this result have to exist? source or target?